# Phonegap (android) - Enable URL TextView in InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova

How do I enable the URL field in the InAppBrowser in Phonegap 2.5.0 running on Android? Currently when I tap the field to type a URL, nothing happens (although in Eclipse it is reporting "TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.").

Comment: UPDATE: I found the line causing the non-editable text. Comment out line 375 of the InAppBrowser.java file (yourproject>src>org.apache.cordova>InAppBrowser.java). Just remember that you now have a custom version of cordova and will not be able to upgrade your cordova lib without making this change again. The best solution would be to move your change into a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is by design. The location in that text field is not editable. If you want that type of functionality you may want to go back to using the [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) or edit the [InAppBrowser](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/InAppBrowser.java;h=886a95b02ef90fb4b10ddbdd7a31b1c8219dee75;hb=25aef945d14eae7167ece73c11e32d8471114bee) code yourself.